# Assigning integers fields/properties to zero in a constructor

Tags: c#

During a recent code review a colleague suggested that, for class with 4 int properties, assigning each to zero in the constructor would result in a performance penalty.

For example,

```
    public Example()
    {
        this.major = 0;
        this.minor = 0;
        this.revision = 0;
        this.build = 0;
    }
```

His point was that this is redundant as they will be set to zero by default and you are introducing overhead by essentially performing the same task twice. My point was that the performance hit would be negligible if one existed at all and this is more readable (there are several constructors) as the intention of the state of the object after calling this constructor is very clear.

What do you think? Is there a performance gain worth caring about here?

Comment: Beware of premature (possible) optimization.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: If this was `programmers.stackexchange.com` I'd answer from a readability point of view. Sure, it's not going to affect performance, but it adds noise to the source code. It's like, say, writing `foreach (var item in someEnumerable.ToList())`.

Comment: i don't like them, they are redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe they're the same operation, and there *is* a performance difference. Here's a microbenchmark to show it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class With
{
    int x;

    public With()
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}


class Without
{
    int x;

    public Without()
    {
    }
}


class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int iterations = int.Parse(args[0]);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        if (args[1] == "with")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                new With();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
            {
                new Without();
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>test 1000000000 with
8427

c:\Users\Jon\Test>test 1000000000 without
881

c:\Users\Jon\Test>test 1000000000 with
7568

c:\Users\Jon\Test>test 1000000000 without
819
```

Now, would that make me change the code? Absolutely not. Write the most readable code first. **If** it's more readable with the assignment, keep the assignment there. Even though a microbenchmark shows it has a cost, that's still a small cost in the context of doing any *real* work. Even though the proportional difference is high, it's still creating a *billion* instances in 8 seconds in the "slow" route. My guess is that there's actually some sort of optimization for completely-empty constructors chaining directly to the completely empty `object()` constructor. The difference between assigning to *two* fields and only assigning to *one* field is much smaller.

In terms of while the compiler can't optimize it out, bear in mind that a base constructor could be modifying the value by reflection, or perhaps a virtual method call. The compiler could *potentially* notice those, but it seems a strange optimization.

Comment: Thanks Jon, always appreciate bench tests etc. in an answer.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not.  The compiler will optimize out these operations; the same task will not be performed twice.  Your colleague is wrong.

[Edit based upon input from the always-excellent Jon Skeet]

The compiler SHOULD optimize out the operations, but apparently they are not completely optimized out; however, the optimization gain is completely negligible, and the benefit from having the assignment be so explicit is good.  Your colleague may not be completely wrong, but they're focusing on a completely trivial optimization.

Comment: Which compiler are you saying will optimize it? The C# compiler doesn't, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I don't think they are the same operation. One is a memory wipe,  the other is explicit assignment. I see no reason to assume this would be removed.

Comment: You're missing here the optimization the JIT/Runtime does. I'm pretty sure this is optimized away. [Edit:] Could be only some runtimes optimize it away.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that objects memory is cleared to zero with a simple and very fast memory wipe. these explicit assignments, however, will take additional IL. Indeed, some tools will spot you assigning the default value (in a field initialiser) and advise against it.

So I would say: don't do this - it is potentially *marginally* slower. But not by much. In short I think your friend is correct.

Unfortunately I'm on a mobile device right now, without the right tools to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

You should focus on code clarity, that is the most important thing. If performance becomes an issue, then measure performance, and see what your bottlenecks are, and improve them. It's not worth it to spend so much time worrying about performance when ease of understanding code is more important.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize them as fields directly:

```
public int number = 0;
```

And is also clear.

Comment: And is also optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: As far as I know is NOT optimized by the compiler but the performance penalty is so so low that it is not even worth calling it a "penalty".

Comment: I also did a billion tests of 5 different ways of doing it. No initialization (21.9 sec), field initialization to 0 (26.4 sec), field initialization to 1 (25.2 sec), constructor to 0 (24.7 seconds), constructor to 1 (24.2 seconds). It's all really close, but not initializing is trivially faster, followed by constructor initialization, then surprisingly direct field initialization. Also surpirsing is that initializing to 1 is about half a billionth of a second faster than initializing to 0!

Answer (score 1):

The more important question is: Is there a really readability gain? If the people who are maintaining the code already know that ints are assigned to zero, this is just some more code they have to parse. Perhaps the code would be cleaner without lines that do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I'd use the assignment in constructor, just for readability, and for marking the 'I didn't forget to initialize those' intention. Relying on default behavior tends to confuse another developers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should care about performance hit, usually there are many other places where program can be optimized. On the other hand I don't see any gain from specifying these values in the constructor since they are going to be set to 0 anyway.